# How to send email notification based on newly posted job ad alone in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a mailer for a job board which entails sending an email notification to subscribers based on jobs posted within every 12 hours.

**send_post_email.html.erb(Mailer Template)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h3> Hi, new job just posted on FarFlungJobs.com! </h3>
  </div>

  <section>
    <p>Fresh Job</p>
    <hr>
    <p>
        <%= Job.select do |job| %>
            <section class="container">
              <div class="row jobs">
                <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size: 20px;"><strong><%= job.company_name %></strong></div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size: 20px;"><%= link_to(job.title, job) %></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right" style="font-size: 20px; float: left;"><%= job.created_at.strftime('%d %B %y') %></div>
              </div>
              <%= render 'shared/two_breaks'%>
            </section>
        <% end %>
    </p>

    <p>Thanks for subscribing to FarFlungJobs once again. <%=  jobs_url %> </p>

  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**job_notifier.rb**

```
class JobNotifier < ApplicationMailer
  def send_post_email(job)
    @user = User.where(:email => true).all
    emails = @user.collect(&:email).join("#{','}")
    @jobs = job
    @job = job
    mail(:to => emails, :bcc => User.pluck(:email).uniq, :subject => 'New job posted on FarFlungJobs')
  end
end
```

**jobs_controller.rb**

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
 def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    if !(@job.paid?)
      @job.update_attributes(stripeEmail: params[:stripeEmail], payola_sale_guid: params[:payola_sale_guid])
        if @job.paid?
          JobNotifier.send_post_email(@job).deliver_now
        end
      @job.update(job_params) if params.has_key?(:job)
      redirect_to  preview_job_path(@job) #show_job_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

**job.rb(model)**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.jobs_posted_12hrs_ago
    where.not('stripeEmail' => nil).where.not('payola_sale_guid' => nil).where('created_at > ?', 18.hours.ago)
  end
end
```

**Note**: This sends emails, but **it sends all the posted jobs** in the database, which I dont want.

> What I like to do is send *just the newly posted jobs within the last 12 hours* to emails subscribers.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, you should have a job (ActiveJob) that uses the scope you defined in the "Job" model, and set it to repeat daily, you have to use a job server like sidekiq or any other, info [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html).

The job should look something like this.

```
class NewJobsMailer < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*guests)
    jobs = Job.jobs_posted_12hrs_ago
    jobs.each do
     JobNotifier.send_post_email(@job).deliver_now
    end
  end
end
```

Its not perfect, but i hope you can use it as guidelines.

Comment: it's completely oversight to me that that am calling all Jobs to be sent in my job_notifier.rb and your answer brough me back to my senses to call the scope instead of all job.